# Is this too much data that should be used in a Struct?

Tags: c#

```
public struct Cache {
    public int babyGangters { get; set; }
    public int punks { get; set; }
    public int ogs { get; set; }
    public int mercs { get; set; }
    public int hsPushers { get; set; }
    public int collegeDealers { get; set; }
    public int drugLords { get; set; }
    public int streetHoes { get; set; }
    public int webcamGrls { get; set; }
    public int escort { get; set; }
    public int turns { get; set; }
    public int cash { get; set; }
    public int bank { get; set; }
    public int drugs { get; set; }
    public int totalValue { get; set; }
    public int attackIns { get; set; }
    public int attackOuts { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public int location { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: A little off-topic, but you might want to consider renaming that struct.

Comment: man, that's quite a game you're creating there

Comment: Also, you might consider making "cash" and/or "bank" non-integral data types.

Comment: You just wanted to see if you could trash talk without anyone noticing didn't you? ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's not only too big by most guidelines, but it's also mutable. That's a much bigger red flag in my view.

Mutable structs can cause unexpected behaviour in many situations. [Just say "no".](https://ericlippert.com/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs/)

Why do you *want* this to be a struct in the first place? And does it really need to be mutable?

Comment: If it isn't mutable, then setting 19 properties will require copying 19 structs.  Provided one uses proper semantics with them, there's nothing wrong with mutable structs.  In particular, don't attempt to access fields or properties of any struct other than a variable, field, or array element; don't create properties of type 'struct', and don't have functions return mutable structs.  If a function should output a struct, pass it by reference.

Comment: @supercat: You're assuming that you'd want to alter all the properties individually, rather than in one go. As soon as you start having to put a bunch of extra restrictions on how you use a mutable struct, I'd generally rather avoid it in the first place. As I say, they can behave unexpectedly in various situations - I still think they're best avoided.

Comment: Whether a struct is good or bad depends on the application.  Mutable structs are IMHO just fine if the typical usage scenario will be: Fetch structure.  Make changes to it.  Shove it back.  Further, arrays of mutable structs can often be more practical than arrays of objects.  I don't like mutable structs that aren't essentially "plain old data", but POD mutable structs seem perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: @supercat: Rather you than me, is all I can say. There are enough corner cases to make the whole thing very risky, IMO.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Explain how you'd handle this: many varied classes have bunches of attributes that may be usefully handled as a group (e.g. color, dimensions, etc.).  If these classes support GetVisAttributes and SetVisAttributes methods return/accept a struct, the semantics are clear.  If GetVisAttributes instead returns a class, should it return (1) a possibly-shared class instance, (2) the underlying class instance, which is guaranteed not to be shared, or (3) a new class instance?

Comment: @supercat: I'd typically make it an immutable type in either case - and decide between a struct or a class based on other considerations. I wouldn't make it a mutable struct.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Each of those three approaches will be the best one in some circumstances.  In scenario #1, the class should be immutable (with the pros/cons that go along with that).  In scenario #2, the object reference should be immutable if the object isn't; this approach can work nicely, but the object returning the class reference will generally forfeit control over how/when it's changed.  BTW, another possibility: (4) an object whose getters/setters tie it back to the original owner.  Workable, but sometimes clunky.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: So you'd say thisAttribute = thisAttribute.WithWidth(5).withDepth(9).WithColor(Color.Red) etc.?  To my mind, that seems a bit clunky.

Comment: @superclunky: Or I'd use a builder pattern: `thisAttribute = new AttributeType.Builder(thisAttribute) { Width = 5, Depth = 9, Color = Red }.Build();` (That's what we do for protocol buffers.)

Answer (score 8):

The rule of thumb is that a struct should not be bigger than 16 bytes (according to the [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321246756)). Your struct is 76 bytes (= 19 * 4), so it is pretty big. However, you will have to measure the performance. Big structs can be beneficial for some applications.

The Framework Design Guidelines state:

> Avoid defining a struct unless the
>   type [...] an instance size under 16
>   bytes.

One of the annotations from Jeffrey Richterto this guidlines state:

> Value types can be more than 16
>   bytes if you don't intend to pass them
>   to other methods or copy them to and
>   from a collection class (like an
>   array).

Comment: This might be a useful response if the logic behind the guideline was given. As stated, it seems not only pretty arbitrary, but unrealistic given that 16 bytes only allows for example, two doubles. Why bother with a struct at all if it's to be limited to 16 bytes?

Comment: @Mickeyf: You are right. I didn't have the book nearby. I updated my answer with quotes from the book.

Answer (score 4):

There is no hard and fast rule as to what constitutes a struct that is too big.  There several guidelines available.  Most notably the .Net Design Guidelines which *recomend* a struct [not exceed 16 bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y23b5415%28VS.71%29.aspx) in size.

However these are just guidelines.  Whether or not a struct is too big depends highly on the context in which it is used.  For example if the struct is created once and only passed by `ref` / `out` to all functions then it's size is much less important than one which is frequently passed by value.

Answer (score 4):

In .Net, use classes unless you have a good reason not to.  "I want it on the stack" with no other qualifiers is not usually a good reason.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/structs_in_csharp.aspx

struct improve memory e speed performance, but must be small, in this case utilize a class.

Comment: Blanket statements like "structs improve memory speed performance" are pretty hard to defend.  Structs *can* improve performance in some situations. But there are other situations in which using a struct incurs a very large performance penalty, even if the structs are small.

Answer (score 1):

If the item is a struct, any attempt to change a field will only change the field in that particular struct instance.  In some circumstances, .net will create temporary struct instances, and if you're not careful your attempts to change a field will simply change the field in that temp instance, rather than in anything more persistent.  That is the 'gotcha' that Jon Skeet is warning you about.

On the other hand, a struct variable does have the advantage that value types within it can only be changed if that variable itself is written.  The risk that an attempt to change a temporary struct might fail (described above) should be weighed against the risk that an two class variables might get aliased to the same object when they should in reality point to two different objects which happen to have the same property values.  If that happens, a change to one variable might accidentally change the other.

One way to think of a struct is like a class which gets cloned any time it gets passed around, but with a cloning operation that's cheaper than that of a class.  If 10%-50% or more of the uses of a class would require that it be cloned, you're probably better off with a struct.  If you would mostly be using it without cloning it, use a class.

BTW, I wouldn't bother with settable properties; if something is settable, just make the field public.  Since structs can't be inherited, there's no loss of generality.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer that because this depends on your application and usage.

However, yes, with this much data you should really think about creating a `class` instead of a `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also ask yourself if you can logically group some of those fields into structs or classes.

Answer (score 0):

The decision as to whether or not to use a struct should be based more on how you want to use it than on how large it is.  You should ask yourself if there's any compelling benefit to making this a struct instead of a class.  Do you really need value type semantics?  Do you need to allocate tens of millions of these things and can't pay the allocation overhead (12 or 24 bytes, depending on the platform) if they're classes?  I suspect that the answer to both of those questions is "No", so it's likely that you want to make this thing a class rather than a struct.